# Servicestack Razor Markdown View Resolution

Tags: servicestack

I want to display a view after facebook authentication in my application but I'm getting the **json response** instead the **html view**, according to [the documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/Docs/markdown/markdown-features.md) the view resolution is the following:

The resolution order ServiceStack's uses to resolve the appropriate Markdown template to use for rendering HTML output is:

1. If the Web Service specifies a template (via a customized IHttpResult.**TemplateName** response) - then a View with that name.
2. **A view with the same name as the Response DTO, looking first in /Views then in /Views/Shared**
3. A view with the same name as the Request DTO, looking first in /Views then in /Views/Shared

these are my DTOs

```
 public class FacebookRequest{}
 public class FacebookResponse{}
```

this is my route configuration

```
Routes.Add<FacebookRequest>("/User/facebook");
```

my view has the folloing code:

```
@inherits ViewPage<MyProject.Services.Dto.FacebookResponse>

this is a facebook response
```

Service method:

```
 [ClientCanSwapTemplates]
  public FacebookResponse Get(FacebookRequest userRequest)
  {
      return new FacebookResponse();
  }
```

As far as I understand if I have a view located in the "views" directory with the same responseDTO it should wire the view with the response from the service.

Comment: I don't get your question clearly but http://razor.servicestack.net/ project will help you to understand view things. Please can you pin point the things where you are stuck?

Comment: Is the name of your view `FacebookResponse.cshtml` or  `FacebookResponse.md`?  Is it located in your /Views or /Views/Shared directory?  Your question doesn't state that explicitly.

Comment: @kunjee hi I was getting a json response instead a html view

Comment: @marfarma the files are .cshtml and they are located in a folder named "views" it supposed if I got a responseDTO associated with a viewpage it should pick that up automatically, what I had to do was to define an attribute [DefaultView("name of the view")] explicitly to the view that I needed to render, but I'm still wondering why I had to do that.

Comment: SS uses the exact name of the response DTO class and looks for a view file with that exact name on the filesystem, unless you provide a DefaultView attribute.  So, if your view (in your example) wasn't `Views/FacebookResponse.cshtml` exactly, it won't work.  Using the `inherits viewpage` statement doesn't help SS resolve the view.  It's looking for the exact file name in a specific location.  I'm not 100% on this - but I seem to recall that it was a case sensitive match too.

Comment: @marfarma thanks men! I see my mistake now the viewname is facebook.cshtml and not facebookResponse.cshtml got it!

Comment: Great! I've added my comment as an 'answer' - please mark it as selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Adding comment as answer*

SS uses the exact name of the response DTO class and looks for a view file with that exact name on the filesystem, unless you provide a DefaultView attribute. So, if your view (in your example) wasn't Views/FacebookResponse.cshtml exactly, it won't work. Using the inherits viewpage statement doesn't help SS resolve the view. It's looking for the exact file name in a specific location. I'm not 100% on this - but I seem to recall that it was a case sensitive match too.